# How do I properly breadcrumb meat?

Tags: meat, breadcrumbs

I have always breadcrumbed meat in a certain way (cordon bleus, schnitzels). But the crumbs on the food are nowhere near a standard that I would make this for guests.

The crumbs always come off, whether  in the pan (while turning), or when we eat it and the whole crust just comes off as one big piece.

Method:
I use 4 bowls.

1. Milk
2. Cake flour
3. egg yolk
4. Bread crumbs

I dip the meat in the same order as above and as properly as I can. Then it’s over to the pan on medium heat and a small layer of oil.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: @user23614 please don't answer in comments. Even if you haven't tried yet what you suggest, post it as an answer and indicate so.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/53390/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/30113/67

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem that most people make when doing a breading is that they try to put on too thick of a coating of any given layer.

Breading sticks because wet sticks to dry, and visa-versa.  As such, you need to give the item a good shake after it leaves each dry station, and a moment or so to drip (and a little bit of shaking here helps, too) after it leaves a wet station.

I've also seen recommendations to let the breaded item sit for a while before cooking -- I can only assume that this is to allow moisture to migrate into the dry breading, or for the egg to set up some before it turns to steam (which could result in that layer separating).

So, some suggestions to fix your recipe:

1. Don't use the milk, but also don't dry your meat.
2. Use whole eggs, but make sure they're well beaten (the color will go to a pale yellow).  The whites act as more of a 'glue' while the yolks only serve to wet things down.
3. Make sure to shake the item after it's gone in the flour.
4. If the eggs layer is going on too thickly, thin it with a bit of water before you do the next item.
5. Really press the crumbs in on the final station.  Shake the container to get a good distribution, then set the item in there.  Spoon the crumbs from the side on top of the item 'til you can't see it, then press the crumbs into the item.
6. Shake the item as it comes out of the breadcrumb station, or leave it to set for a few minutes on a sheet tray or wire rack, or both.

Comment: The thing about resting or not - seems to be one of *absolutely necessary* vs. *under no circumstances* cases. Sources vary wildly. I usually wing it and usually am ok. Good answer, nevertheless!

Comment: Followed your advice. And wala, its perfect now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest not dipping in the milk first, just flour the meat. Dip in the egg, then press hard into the breadcrumbs.

Use more than a thin layer of oil as well - around a 1 cm layer of oil would be about right.

Answer (score 3):

The heat of the pan can make a difference too. Try medium high. I find that breaded / battered materials stay crunchier when cooked on higher heats.